# Calling class object from a function without insert it to the function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop

We have this code in 'Reconstruction the subclass object from a saved struct' from MATLAB OOP documentation.

```
 classdef MySuper
    % Superclass definition
    properties
        X
        Y
    end
    methods
        function S = saveobj(obj)
            % Save property values in struct
            % Return struct for save function to write to MAT-file
            S.PointX = obj.X;
            S.PointY = obj.Y;
        end
        function obj = reload(obj,S)
            % Method used to assign values from struct to properties
            % Called by loadobj and subclass
            obj.X = S.PointX;
            obj.Y = S.PointY;
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function obj = loadobj(S)
            % Constructs a MySuper object
            % loadobj used when a superclass object is saved directly
            % Calls reload to assign property values retrived from struct
            % loadobj must be Static so it can be called without object
            obj = MySuper;
            obj = reload(obj,S);
        end
    end
end
```

I have a question about `obj = MySuper`. What is purpose of this line? How we can call `MySuper` object from this function without insert any object to `loadobj` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first question is: What is the purpose of the `obj = MySuper;` line?

The answer is that the `obj = MySuper;` line initiates the variable `obj` as an element of the class `MySuper`. Non-static functions in a class will only run if the first input parameter is an instance of the class, so if `obj` is not initiated as a `MySuper`-object, then matlab will look for other functions called `reload` to run, and if none is found give you an error.

For your second question, I am not 100% sure what you mean. But I hope one of the following points will answer your question:

If you want to make a function that relates to a class, but not to a specific instance of the class, you can make a static function, these can take any input (also (if you want it that way) no input at all) - that is they don't need to have a first input parameter of the specific class.

To run a static function, use the class name followed by a dot and then the function name, so here you would type `MySuper.loadobj(S)` to run the function with the parameter `S`.
I would suggest that you try this out with the given example to better get to know the way oop works in matlab, you may for example try:

```
S.PointX = 1;
S.PointY = 2;
obj = MySuper.loadobj(S)
```

I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you for answer Jens Boldsen.